# css effect not working in IE

Tags: css

I have a basic code which has to align the size of the image based on the resolution of the screen... this script works fine on a Mozilla but completely fails in IE.. here's a sample code..

```
<html>
<style>
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
#bar{width:90px;height:7px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <p>
      <img id="bar" src="bgn.jpg">
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

is there any tweak or any thing I have to include in the script...

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for a efficient fallback for IE6 and up.

Comment: Modernizr provides a fallback for CSS3 media queries - it's the only way to make them work in old IEs.

Comment: ok...i was looking at this site on how to use modernizr... every where it is mentioned that the it loads things dynamically... does that mean one has to have internet connection for modernizr to work???

Comment: Modernizr itself works without an internet connection - I have used it locally for some time now. Whatever you want to do with it offline?

Answer (score -1):

Doctype is missing

Use `<!DOCTYPE html>`